# Magento No free Shipping for wholesale customer

Tags: magento-1.9, php, ce-1.9.1.0, customer-group, free-shipping

In Magento 1.9.1  I have enabled the `free shipping for minimum order amount`(i.e. $75) from ***System >> Configuration >> Shipping Methods >> FedEx***.

[image]

It’s working fine for all customers as expected, but I want, `wholesale customer` can pay the **full shipping amount**. No shipping discount/ free for wholesale customer.

Can  anyone tell/suggest me how to do that or how to set a `shopping rule` for that?

Comment: this may work :  create the 2 Shopping cart price rules in Admin panel. one for wholesale customers and other for all customers....

Path : 

   `Admin => Promotions => Shopping Cart Price Rules` => Add New Rule`....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I have tried from there also but failed to set the exact condition

Comment: you need to set select customer groups from here : `Customer Groups` tab & under `condition` tab you need to select `shipping method`......

Comment: @BabyinMagento yes tried but not working. we are  allowing 3 shipping  method Home delivery, Express saver, 2day. from configuration section  we  have set free shipping (above 75 order price) for home delivery only. but this condition is apply to all customer. I don't want this for wholesale group customer.

Comment: i hope  you already unselected `wholesale` customer group in shopping cart rule, okay also check the priority of `shopping cart price rules` keep the `home delivery` cart rule to `priority 1` and other cart rules to higher priority.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I have tried but not working